# What happens if a lysosome is pierced and it's enzymes are made to get released

Tags: cell-biology, botany, eukaryotic-cells

I am confused the results be same as it happens when lysosome gets damaged during some metabolic activity or different . If same  the cell will die by the actions of those hydrolytic enzymes slowly or immediately , I think the results might differ from the accidental case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enzymes of lysosome are usually inactive and are activated only in low pH environments, so I guess, randomly puncturing a lysosome wouldn't affect the cell to any serious extent unless the cell is an acid secretory cell or It's membrane is easily permeable.